# Why does this code give an error?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$("#main").animate({ 
display: "block",
width: "70%",
opacity: 0.4,
marginLeft: "0.6in",
fontSize: "3em", 
borderWidth: "10px"
} 1500);
```

This is jQuery.  I get a "missing ) after arguement list" message.  What's wrong?

Comment: just in case you didn't know yet, you missed a comma (lol) .. I just had to write this comment after reading the answers

Comment: @jAndy - yeah! you spotted it!... I myself was wondering all this long what was giving the error... thanks!! :)

Comment: I frightened myself how quick I figured that out!

Comment: I guess the OP is looking for the comma right now... hmmm... where is it?!!!...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

umm

```
} 1500);
```

missing comma before 1500

may i suggest using http://www.jslint.com/ for this in the future? if you paste in that code block in there you will get the following errors:

```
Error:
Problem at line 8 character 3: Expected ')' and instead saw '1500'.

} 1500);

Problem at line 8 character 7: Missing semicolon.

} 1500);

Problem at line 8 character 7: Expected an identifier and instead saw ')'.

} 1500);

Problem at line 8 character 7: Stopping, unable to continue. (100% scanned).

Implied global: $ 1
```

after that, it its pretty easy to see that your error must be on line 8..

Answer (score 3):

You need a comma before the duration at the end (currently `} 1500);`), like this:

```
$("#main").animate({ 
display: "block",
width: "70%",
opacity: 0.4,
marginLeft: "0.6in",
fontSize: "3em", 
borderWidth: "10px"
}, 1500);
```

Answer (score 3):

```
$("#main").animate({ 
display: "block",
width: "70%",
opacity: 0.4,
marginLeft: "0.6in",
fontSize: "3em", 
borderWidth: "10px"
}, 1500); // you have forgotten the comma here...
```